# Increment operator in C

Tags: c

I tried the following code snippet:

```
void main()
{
    int x = 1,y = 1,z = 1;
    ++x || ++y && ++z;
    printf("x = %d\ny = %d\nz = %d\n",x,y,z);
}
```

The output I *expected* was:

```
x = 2
y = 2
z = 2
```

But I am getting the output:

```
x = 2
y = 1
z = 1
```

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because of short-circuiting.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

When this is evaluated:

```
++x || ++y && ++z;
```

The first part `++x` already determines the value of the entire expression. So the `++y && ++z` is not executed at all. So the side-effects of `++y` and `++z` are not invoked.

Answer (score 3):

The result of `++x` is nonzero, so evaluates to true, so short-circuits the `||` operator. `++y && ++z` is not executed.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is you're using Brobdingnagian boolean expressions with side effects.

The operators `&&` and `||` are "short-circuiting". That means if the result of the expression is determined after the left operand is evaluated, the right operand never gets evaluated.

Avoid using expression with side-effects as operands of boolean operators. Even if the behaviour is what you want.

Comment: +1 for introducing me to the word "Brobdingnagian" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brobdingnag)